# JGit checkout over the same branch

Tags: java, jgit

I need to sequentially check out tags over a branch I created with JGit.

```
CheckoutCommand checkout = new Git(testRepository).checkout();

if (!branchExists())
    checkout.setCreateBranch(true).setName("branch-for-test").setStartPoint(key);
else
    checkout.setName(key);

checkout.call();
```

Where `key` is a `String` which contains the name of the commit I want to checkout (`key` changes in a loop). I don't want to create a branch each time I checkout as I don't need to. The following error is shown:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Could not rename file target\TestRepository\server\db\scripts\postgresql\._db_script.sql6197897692249726905.tmp to target\TestRepository\server\db\scripts\postgresql\_db_script.sql
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:320)
```

Before this happened I was trying to checkout inside the else statement with

```
checkout.setName("branch-for-test").setStartPoint(key);
```

It did not throw any error but it did not checkout the tag either.

Comment: What does `branchExists()` do? Does it check if a branch named `branch-for-test`exists? If so, creating the branch could be moved outside of the loop, right?

Comment: The intention is to verify if the branch was already created, in that case I would like to checkout in that existing branch

Comment: Checking out into the same branch should work. You should find the reason for the 'could not rename' exception. Did you set a breakpoint on the line (or before) that throws the exception to see what is going on (e.g. does the target file exist, etc.)?

Comment: Sorry to answer so late. There's a temp file that cannot be renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that using JGit in Windows may generate conflicts related to managed files sometimes. What I made for solving this recurrent issue was to execute a `git clean --force` followed by a `git reset --hard` before each `git checkout <ref_name>`. This was totally fine for me, as I didn't need to stage changes...

The problem was that basically after using some files (even in a read-only way), they were marked as changed (I verified it with `git status`). The solution explained above implied more operations, but totally solved my problem.

For further details, refer to git documentation about these actions:

- [Git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean): Removes untracked files from the working tree.
- [Git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset): Resets current HEAD to the specified state.

And develop the appropiate implementation of these two actions with JGit:

- Clean with [Clean Command](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.5.0.201609210915-r/org.eclipse.jgit/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CleanCommand.html).
- Reset with [Reset Command](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/ResetCommand.html)